# F# quotation with spliced parameter of any type

Tags: f#, type-providers, quotations

I am trying to develop F# type provider.
It provides some DTOs (with the structure described in some external document) and a set of methods for processing them. The processing algorithm is based on reflection, and I want to have a single quotation representing it.
Generally, this algorithm must pass all method call arguments to the already written function `serialize: obj -> MySerializationFormat`, storing all results in a list, so I getting a value of `MySerializationFormat list`.

Code sample below shows, how I tried to do that for first time:

```
let serialize (value: obj) = ...
let processingCode: Expr list -> Expr = 
    fun args ->   
        let serializeArgExpr (arg: Expr) = <@ serialize %%arg} @>
        let argsExprs = List.map serializeArgExpr args
        let serializedArgList = 
            List.foldBack (fun head tail -> <@ (%head) :: (%tail)@>) argsExprs <@ [] @> 
        // futher processing
```

At that point I faced with exception: In function `serializeArgExpr` the actual type of value in `arg: Expr` may vary, it can be some primitive type (e.g `string`, `int`, `float`), or some provided type. The problem is `%%` operator treats that `arg` as an expression of the `obj` type. Type check is performed on [that line in Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/36bdf17f51f673ab1c04b9fc1b4e5b450e71a2d6/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/quotations.fs#L1733) module, in function `fillHolesInRawExpr`.
So, as the actual type of my term not matched the treated type for "hole" in the quotation, it throws `invalidArg`.

I have tried several technics to avoid these exceptions with casting operations in my quotation, but they don't work. Then I found `Expr.Coerce(source, target)` function, which looks like solving my problem. I have changed the code of `serializeArgExpr` to something like that:

```
let serializeArgExpr (arg: Expr) =
    let value' = Expr.Coerce(value, typeof<obj>)
    <@ serialize %%value' } @>
```

Then faced a new strange exception:

> The design-time type (point to a code line that uses my `processingCode`) utilized by a type provider was not found in the target reference assembly set

For me, it seems that my problem is to cast the type of value in any input `Expr` to an `obj` type. Thank you for diving in and trying to help.

Comment: My guess is that the issue is actually unrelated to what you're doing. I think your use of `Coerce` is fine. Maybe this now works and you are getting a different error (which you previously didn't get, because it got stuck on something else earlier). The "design-time type not found" error is a nightmare error related to assembly loading in type provider. Perhaps something from here might help? https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/3303#issuecomment-506907174